# I can't get my odata query to count nested elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to count related objects in a odata query but I don't get the summarized result, only the details

If I count the first object type that works fine...

```
.../ObjectType1?$apply=groupby((ObjectType1Type),aggregate(Id with countdistinct as total))
```

I get this as expected result...

```
[
    {
        "ObjectType1Type": "Type1",
        "total": 15
    },
    {
        "ObjectType1Type": "Type2",
        "total": 1
    }
]
```

If I count the second object type that works fine...

```
.../ObjectType2?$apply=groupby((ObjectType2Type),aggregate(Id with countdistinct as total))
```

I get this as expected result...

```
[
    {
        "ObjectType2Type": "Type1",
        "total": 13
    },
    {
        "ObjectType2Type": "Type2",
        "total": 15
    },
    {
        "ObjectType2Type": "Type3",
        "total": 13
    },
    {
        "ObjectType2Type": "Type4",
        "total": 15
    }
]
```

If I ask to get one object and count all its related objects...

```
.../ObjectType1(Id)?$expand=ObjectType2($apply=groupby((ObjectType2Type),aggregate(Id with countdistinct as total)))
```

I'm getting this, which I don't expect...

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://localhost:44391/v1.0/odata/$metadata#Objects1(Objects2())/$entity",
    "Id": "50e445b9-ad81-4919-b7b9-4b11b67277d5",
    "ObjectType1": "Type1",
    "Name": "My Object",
    "Timestamp": "2018-11-14T16:26:28+0000",
    "Message": "This is the message",
    "ObjectType2": [
        {
            "Id": "6778883d-df2a-4ec6-adaf-fcd05d7f4a5f",
            "ObjectType2Type": "Type1"
        },
        {
            "Id": "19d46eb7-c0dc-478c-a522-9b0c928b29c4",
            "ObjectType2Type": "Type1"
        },
        {
            "Id": "79cffedd-2243-4725-bfd5-a592ff599fa5",
            "ObjectType2Type": "Type1"
        },
        {
            "Id": "e119dd31-8521-45c4-b4da-8fab691cdd93",
            "ObjectType2Type": "Type1"
        },
        {
            "Id": "9a188e60-30ed-4b77-a358-e75ffc829362",
            "ObjectType2Type": "Type1"
        },
        {
            "Id": "0b06e260-87ef-42b9-87c4-bf8e63395a36",
            "ObjectType2Type": "Type1"
        },
        {
            "Id": "d5a6ef17-710c-4761-b5d0-7f609ac07f1a",
            "ObjectType2Type": "Type1"
        },
        {
            "Id": "3133d38d-84a3-4502-b661-3a8ecdc4a5c9",
            "ObjectType2Type": "Type1"
        },
        {
            "Id": "89760715-86fd-4e8d-98e6-b755854ce1e7",
            "ObjectType2Type": "Type1"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would expect the following...
(According to [Odata definition](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-data-aggregation-ext/v4.0/cs02/odata-data-aggregation-ext-v4.0-cs02.html#_Toc435016591))

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://localhost:44391/v1.0/odata/$metadata#Nodes(Relationships())/$entity",
    "Id": "50e445b9-ad81-4919-b7b9-4b11b67277d5",
    "ObjectType1": "Type1",
    "Name": "My Object",
    "Timestamp": "2018-11-14T16:26:28+0000",
    "Message": "This is the message",
    "ObjectType2": [
        {
            "ObjectType2Type": "Type1",
            "total": 9
        }
    ]
}
```

**Should this work?
What am I missing?**

The versions of the related nugets are...

- "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning" Version="3.0.0"
- "Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData" Version="7.1.0"
- "Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Versioning" Version="3.0.0"
- "Microsoft.OData.Core" Version="7.6.0"